# ExtJS - How to Set Up Binding with Deep Config on ViewModel Formula

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS window populated with panels (extended) using binds to display data based on JSON objects (stored on ViewModel).  One of the bound fields is a formula calculated from the values of properties on the JSON object associated with each panel. I am programmatically updating the value on one of the properties on a specific event and want the formula to be re-evaluated and update the screen.

I'm able to get this to happen by explicitly setting the data on the ViewModel to a clone of the original with the applicable properties changed. However it's my understanding based on opinions seen in other posts/boards regarding related questions that this would more appropriately be done using the "deep" config that's part of the Binding object.

I've tried changing my binding in each of the places that seemed likely in order to add the deep config (on the panel, in the formula on the ViewModel, etc), but have not managed to get to change the value on the screen even though the underlying JSON object's property has successfully been changed.

The following is a fiddle where I simplified the issue as much as possible to reproduce:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.BindTesting', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'vbox',

    viewModel: {
        data: {
            testObject: {
                a: 'sixteen',
                b: 'two',
                c: 'three',
                d: 'one',
                e: 1
            }
        },

        formulas: {
            something: {
                bind: '{testObject}',
                get(info) {
                    return info.a;
                }
            }
        }
    },

    bind: {
        title: 'Current data is {something}'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Change Me',
        handler: function () {
                const me = this,
                    vm = me.ownerCt.getViewModel(),
                    data = vm.get('testObject'),
                    count = data.e;

                if (count % 2 === 0) {
                    data.a = data.b;
                    console.log('changing to b. a = ' + data.a);
                } else if (count % 3 === 0) {
                    data.a = data.c;
                    console.log('changing to c. a = ' + data.a);
                } else {
                    data.a = data.d;
                    console.log('changing to d. a = ' + data.a);
                }

                data.e++;

                // NOTE - using set makes it work, but this is
                // supposedly bad form and we should use "deep: true"
                // in the binding
                // vm.set('testObject', Ext.clone(data));
            }
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.BindTesting', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 400
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However it's my understanding based on opinions seen in other
>   posts/boards regarding related questions that this would more
>   appropriately be done using the "deep" config that's part of the
>   Binding object.

The `deep` configuration on a binding means to react to changes on child objects, however the viewmodel doesn't actively track changes on the object itself, it requires "notification" (typically via a set) to re-evaluate the object. The approach you outlined in your post is the correct way to do it, though it would be better to clone the object first before mutating:

```
const vm = this.lookupViewModel();
const data = Ext.clone(vm.get('testObject'));
const count = data.e;

if (count % 2 === 0) {
    data.a = data.b;
} else if (count % 3 === 0) {
    data.a = data.c;
} else {
    data.a = data.d;
}

data.e++;

vm.set('testObject', data);
```

Also note, a more idiomatic way to write your formula would be:

```
something: get => get('testObject.a')
```